# Angular Post End Point Many To Many

Tags: angular

i try to add a subject with her level with anngular and .net web api so i establish a ManyToMany between them these are my models :

public class Matiere

```
{
    [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string NomMatiere { get; set; }
     public string DescriptionMatiere { get; set; }
     public string AutheurMatiere { get; set; }
     public byte[] ImageMatiere { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Quiz> Quizzes { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }       
}
```

}`

```
public class Level
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Matiere> Matieres { get; set; }
}
```

}

The next step this is my Post end point i want to add the subject with her level because i want to bind the name of the subject and her level next in the angular side :

```
 [HttpPost("PostMatiere")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddSubject([FromForm] Matiere subObj, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                subObj.ImageMatiere = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        // get the level with the specified id
        var level = await _context.Levels.FindAsync(subObj.Levels.First().Id);

        if (level == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid level id");
        }

        // add the level to the subject
        subObj.Levels = new List<Level> { level };

        await _context.Matieres.AddAsync(subObj);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(new
        {
            StatusCode = 200,
            Message = "Subject Added Successfully"
        });
    }
```

When i debug my app the count of the Levels :**var level = await _context.Levels.FindAsync(subObj.Levels.First().Id); is 0** So my logic is correct or no ?